# Apply middleware to route in Express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I would like to apply a middleware to a route regardless of the type of request. Currently I have:

```
router.route('/campaigns')
    .get(restrictTo('advertiser'), restrictTo('admin'), queries.getCampaigns)
    .post(restrictTo('advertiser'), restrictTo('admin'), queries.createCampaign);
```

And I would like something like:

```
router.route('/campaigns', restrictTo('advertiser'), restrictTo('admin'))
    .get(queries.getCampaigns)
    .post(queries.createCampaign);
```

But this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.all()`

Example:

```
 router.route('/campaigns')
      .all(yourmiddleware)
      .get(function (req, res, next) {
            // your function ...
      })
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The express documentation says that you can do it like that :

```
app.use('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl)
  next()
}, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method)
  next()
})
```

Replace the `/user/:id` to you desired path.

Source : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use `.use()` like so:

```
router.route('/campaigns')
  .use(restrictTo('advertiser'), restrictTo('admin'))
  .get(queries.getCampaigns)
  .post(queries.createCampaign);
```

or:

```
router.route('/campaigns')
  .use(restrictTo('advertiser'))
  .use(restrictTo('admin'))
  .get(queries.getCampaigns)
  .post(queries.createCampaign);
```

Comment: Should be `.all()`, `.use()` only applies to the router in its entirety and not to single routes.